# Need to feed explicit list of VS SLN files to nuget restore task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pipeline, nuget-package-restore

Azure Devops Pipeline Task NuGetRestore@1 not accepting a list of solution files for iteration

In building an Azure Pipeline, I have found that some of my solution files, build code that must be pushed to a Nuget feed before the rest of the solution is built. I've written some Powershell to go off and discern this, and feed the list of files back as variables. In a subsequent, task I then try to use the list of solution files as input to the NuGetRestore@1 task and that is failing.

```
variables:
  SLNFILELIST: 'a/a.sln b/b.sln'

- task: NuGetRestore@1
  displayName: restore slnfilelist
  inputs:
    solution: "$(SLNFILELIST)"
```

Ideally, the NuGetRestore task above would iterate over both solution files a and b in the variable. However I get this (edited) output instead.

```
Active code page: 65001
##[error]Error: Not found files: D:\a\1\s\a\a.sln D:\a\1\s\b\b.sln
##[error]Packages failed to restore
##[section]Finishing: restore slnfilelist
```

To some degree I know there is a iteration mechanism in this task since if the solution is set to a value of "***.sln" the task will go and find all solution files in current working directory and then iterate through them so the task has the ability, the question is how is that fed directly into the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMH, 10 minutes after I posted this, I found the answer in this github issue.

Instead, of a space delimiter, use a semi-colon and it works. :(

[Enable to select multiple input files in NuGet restore task #8369](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8369)